# How can I get text to the left of image inside a div?

Tags: html, css

I want to get my image to the right of the text whilst inside a div. Every tutorial I have seen mentions floats, whilst floats work, it doesn't quite work when inside a div. If I don't put the image in a div and float it, the div below overflows it.

I want it in a div because I want both the text and image to be one item basically.

How can I sort this? Or is there a better way to do this? Code below:

HTML

```
<div class="intro">
    <div class="picture">
        <img class="col-s-3" src="images/my-picture2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="title">
        <p class="col-s-3">INSERT NAME<br>My Portfolio</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The class "col-s-3" is essentially just width = 25%.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="intro">
    <div class="title">
        <p class="col-s-3">INSERT NAME<br>My Portfolio</p>
    </div>
    <div class="picture">
        <img class="col-s-3" src="images/my-picture2.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

.intro {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Best try for this.

Answer (score 0):

Add This CSS on `.intro`

```
.intro{display:flex;}
```